# degree of extension of residue fields of cyclic covers

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $d \geq 2$ be an integer, $k$ a number a field containing $d$-th roots of unity and $X$ and $Y$ smooth varieties over $k$.

Let $\pi: Y \to X$ be an unramified cyclic cover of degree $d$. Let $x$ be a point in $X$, with residue field $k(x)$ and let $y$ be a point in $Y$ such that $\pi(x)=y$. Denote by $k(y)$ the residue field of $y$.

Is it true that $[k(y): k]$ divides $d$? If so, can you help me to prove it?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible because you can simply take $y$ to have huge residue degree. Let me be more precise.

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a finite surjective morphism (unramified is unnecessary)  of smooth varieties over a number field $k$ of degree $d$.

Let $L/k$ be a field extension of **prime** degree $>d$ and $y \in Y(L)\backslash Y(K)$. 
Note that $[k(y) :k]  = [L:K] > d$ does not divide $d$. (Such field extensions $L/K$ exist if $Y$ is a proper curve.)

Nevertheless, by surjectivity there are $d$ points in the pre-image of $y$ (counted with multiplicity). Let $x \in f^{-1}(y)$ so that $f(x) = y$. This contradicts what you are asking for.

Comment: This being said, with the notation of the OP, $[k(y): k(x)]$ divides $d$. This was probably the true question.